# Не работает com.google.android.material.slider.Slider

Tags: android, android-material

Падает приложение при включении в него слайдера из `com.google.android.material.slider.Slider.`

**build.gradle(:app)** содержит:

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
}
```

**res/layout/activity_en.xml** включает эти строки:

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**Ошибка**:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.heatworkapp.EnhetActivity.onCreate(EnhetActivity.java:50)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 3: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0300b3 a=2}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:538)
        at com.google.android.material.resources.MaterialResources.getColorStateList(MaterialResources.java:71)
        at com.google.android.material.resources.TextAppearance.<init>(TextAppearance.java:79)
        at com.google.android.material.resources.MaterialResources.getTextAppearance(MaterialResources.java:135)
        at com.google.android.material.tooltip.TooltipDrawable.loadFromAttributes(TooltipDrawable.java:151)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.material.tooltip.TooltipDrawable.createFromAttributes(TooltipDrawable.java:111)
        at com.google.android.material.slider.BaseSlider.parseLabelDrawable(BaseSlider.java:443)
        at com.google.android.material.slider.BaseSlider.access$100(BaseSlider.java:178)
        at com.google.android.material.slider.BaseSlider$1.createTooltipDrawable(BaseSlider.java:332)
        at com.google.android.material.slider.BaseSlider.createLabelPool(BaseSlider.java:680)
        at com.google.android.material.slider.BaseSlider.setValuesInternal(BaseSlider.java:661)
        at com.google.android.material.slider.BaseSlider.setValues(BaseSlider.java:617)
        at com.google.android.material.slider.BaseSlider.processAttributes(BaseSlider.java:370)
        at com.google.android.material.slider.BaseSlider.<init>(BaseSlider.java:338)
        at com.google.android.material.slider.Slider.<init>(Slider.java:60)
        at com.google.android.material.slider.Slider.<init>(Slider.java:56)
            ... 30 more
```

Пробовал различные версии `material` от стартовой, которая включает слайдеры до абсолютно новой 1.5.0-alpha. Работать с `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar` буду уже в последнюю очередь,  поскольку надо кастомизировать данный слайдер и `material` позволяет это сделать без лишних заморочек и строк кода. Есть у кого мысли и варианты решения?

**upd** попробовал включить другую сущность из `material`, вот эту - `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`. Ошибок нет все работает отлично

**upd2** изменил тему в `AndroidManifest.xml` на `android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents">`. Ошибка осталась

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено. В `AndroidManifest.xml` была изменена данная строка:

версия с ошибкой

```
...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar"
...
```

новая версия, которая устранила ошибку

```
...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar"
...
```